# How to validate user logged in web application (php)?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Good day.

Could someone please tell me how I can control that a user does not enter a web application more than once?

Currently I am controlling it by storing the session that is created in php in a field of a table and through javascript using ajax I consult it every 10 seconds. I think there must be a better way ... thanks !!!

Comment: If they log in again, trash the older session. Requests using the old session should show an error the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And finally solved it by validating that the session created is different from the previous one, thus updating it and the previous user wanting to validate his session in order to make any request will realize that it does not exist and this will remove him from the application .